# Ruby memory profiling heap - Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, profiling, heap-memory, unicorn

I am running Rails4 and Ruby2.0 with 4 workers and very quickly with extremely light traffic the 4 Unicorn workers occupy 4G of memory very soon .

I am trying to profile rails/Ruby heap and having no success to understand what is causing a bloat or if there is a leak

Here are few things I have tried:

- [memprof](https://github.com/ice799/memprof) for profile start and stop. Not in active dev.
- remote-pry

  - Can attach but ObjectSpace doesn't give much because most of the objects are strings and there are no significant other objects and there is no way to find out object references.
  - The app freezes listening for a remote pry connection which makes the app useless and cant really connect to a live app!
- GDB

  - Seems powerful but hard to get it working
  - Keeps complaining about missing C lib etc
  - Most of good hooks are for Ruby Enterprise Edition (REE)
- [Oink](https://github.com/noahd1/oink). good shows which transactions are above a memory threshold
- Sigdump. Works but again only shows count of classes. 1M+ String, 1M+ Array does not tell much if I cannot see the references etc.

  ```
  Built-in objects:
  567,479: TOTAL
  272,576: T_STRING
  112,326: T_ARRAY
  54,764: T_DATA
  49,431: T_NODE
  47,363: T_OBJECT
   9,758: T_HASH
   9,563: T_CLASS
   3,600: T_REGEXP
   2,729: T_ICLASS
   1,948: T_MATCH
  ```
- [memprof](https://github.com/ice799/memprof). Looks really good but not supported for Ruby 1.9+ :(
- bleak_house. Deprecated, says use Kiji which is a ruby runtime by twitter

Of all the above, 
only Oink was useful where I can find out a rails `Controller#show` transaction to have more than 25MB of memory but how do I profile that further?

Comment: Your question is about Oink, but all of the detail is for other solutions you tried and rejected.  Would you consider removing the other solutions and adding more detail about what you've tried in Oink?  As it is, there's not really anything to answer here.